# Compare object to object

Tags: c#

I have 2 variables:

```
object Id = itemType.GetProperty(dataValueField).GetValue(item, null); //=0;

object selectedValue = 0;
```

And want to compare them.

I have tried:

```
var a = Id.Equals(selectedValue);
var b = Id == selectedValue;
var c = Object.Equals(Id, selectedValue);
var d = var x = Object.Equals((Object)Id, (Object)selectedValue);
```

But everything returns false;

---

Update: Id is typeof Int64? and selectedValue is Int32? but == operator works for Int64? and Int32?

Comment: What's the type of `dataValueField`? Can you paste the class for `itemType` and your `item`?

Comment: Why dont you cast the Id value to int and then compare?

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing the instance and thats why they are different. Do you have to use an `object`? Could you cast it to an `int` ?

You could use a custom class and override `Equals()` and the operator `==`.
Take a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But Id and selectedValue should be String types too. Actually are object type parameters in function and I can pass any type of value in this function

Comment: Is it possible to make it generic? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: It could be written like this: 
`int Id = itemType.GetProperty(dataValueField).GetValue<int>(item, null);`

Comment: Generic function would be great idea but GetValue() is not generic type function, s I can't write `int Id = itemType.GetProperty(dataValueField).GetValue<int>(item, null);`

Comment: You could write a generic wrapper method which does the casting for you. But it's hard to make a conclusion without knowing the code in depth.
I hope i helped a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure there is a problem with your data types, not the values. If you for example take `0L` (long) and an integer with value 0, all ways to check equality return `false`. If both have the same type (`int`) for example, it works.

Comment: Id is typeof Int64? and selectedValue is Int32? but == operator works for Int64? and Int32?

Comment: Nope, not this way. `bool x = object.Equals((object)0, (object)0L)` returns false. `bool x = object.Equals((object)0, (object)0)` returns true.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But I am talking about == operator not about Object.Equals(). == operator works fine for Int64? and Int32?

Comment: If they both are typed the right way. You are now comparing objects, not primitive types. There is more logic behind comparing than just the values.

Comment: Yes, indeed and this is my problem that == and Object.Equals() are not working for me. If I cast these object types to Int64? and Int32? it will work. But Id and selectedValue are object type parameters for function and I can pass any type of value in this function

Comment: Yes, it will work then. Make sure to cast them to an `long?` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

> Id is typeof Int64? and selectedValue is Int32? but == operator works for Int64? and Int32?

You are right that those types compare properly:

```
Int64? Id = 0;
Int32? selectedValue = 0;

Console.WriteLine(Id == selectedValue); // indeed true
```

However, your types are `objects`, so you have to keep in mind that what actually happens is a comparison of objects:

```
object IdAsObject = Id;
object selectedValueAsObject = selectedValue;

Console.WriteLine(IdAsObject.Equals(selectedValueAsObject));
Console.WriteLine(IdAsObject == selectedValueAsObject);
Console.WriteLine(Object.Equals(IdAsObject, selectedValueAsObject));
Console.WriteLine(Object.Equals((Object)IdAsObject, (Object)selectedValueAsObject));
```

And these are all false, since two objects are only equal if they are the same object.

If you want to compare the values, you should make sure to use proper types.

Comment: So I have to cast Id and selectedValue to Int64? and Int32? and compare them after this? There is no solution?

Comment: This statement is not correct: `since two objects are only equal if they are the same object`. The `Equals` method has been overridden in Int32 and Int64. The problem here is that the override does a type check first and the type of an Int32 is not the same as an Int64. For now reference, see http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Int64@cs/1305376/Int64@cs. If you want to check it yourself, change both the `Id` and `selectedValue` to be an `int32` (and cast to object) and do an `idAsObect.Equals(selectedValueAsObject)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the source code for `Int64` and `Int32`. Excerpt from `Int64`:

http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Int64@cs/1305376/Int64@cs

```
    public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj is Int64)) {
            return false; 
        }
        return m_value == ((Int64)obj).m_value; 
    }
```

If you notice, the first thing the Equals does is a type check. The types are not compatible and your only solution will be to either cast the `Int32` to an `Int64` or write a custom `Equals` that does what you need.

And some test to demonstrate:

```
public class Blah
{
    public Int32 Id32 { get; set; }
    public Int64 Id64 { get; set; }
}

private void DoTest()
{
    var blah = new Blah
    {
        Id32 = 1,
        Id64 = 1
    };

    object idInt32 = blah.GetType().GetProperty("Id32").GetValue(blah, null);
    object idInt64 = blah.GetType().GetProperty("Id64").GetValue(blah, null);
    object selectedValue = 1; // default type is Int32

    bool areTheSameInt = idInt32.Equals(selectedValue); // true
    bool areTheSameLong = idInt64.Equals(selectedValue); // false
}
```